# BroadCast Receiver does not work on boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

My application contains a broadcast receiver class only. I just want to display a message in the logcat when the phone is fully booted. For this I used "ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED".

BroadCast receiver class

```
package com.example.serviceproject;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

    public class BroadCastClass extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.getAction() != null)
            {
                if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
                {
                    Log.i("BroadCastClass","BOOT COMPLETED detected");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

In the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.serviceproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".BroadCastClass"  android:enabled="true" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when do I boot my phone the message is not displayed in the logcat. i have something wrong ??

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no, i get no error :(

Comment: Check CommonsWare answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723750/broadcasting-of-boot-completed-intent-action-does-not-work-properly?rq=1

Comment: Go through this link , it may be helpful to you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096673/launch-application-without-an-interface-to-receive-boot-completed/11099685#11099685


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408911/broadcast-receiver-not-receiving-action-boot-completed-if-app-hasnt-been-run

Comment: first you had put one wrong code in manifest you cannot declare boot reciver perminision Second in manifeast file put hole class file with package name meance com.example.serviceproject.BroadCastClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code...

```
 package com.example.serviceproject;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;

        public class BroadCastClass extends BroadcastReceiver
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {

                        Log.i("BroadCastClass","BOOT COMPLETED detected");

            }
        };
```

and manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.serviceproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
      android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="BroadCastClass">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i don't have an activity in my application. i have just a broadcast receiver class

Comment: now try by replacing following statement  <receiver android:name="BroadCastClass"> with <receiver android:name=".BroadCastClass">

Comment: ok.. final change remove this statement <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>  from your manifest file

Comment: I think u should use Activity otherwise application many not register your receiver. So please create another example with Activity in your eclipse then register your receiver in manifest file.

Comment: sure.. i will leave my office in halfen hour. so please let me know before that

Comment: coool it works now when i added an activity. thank you very much saa :)

Comment: Ok... i am leaving byeee... Happy Christmas... :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.serviceproject.BroadCastClass" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try and debug the code.Keep your breakpoint inside onReceive() and check whether it goes inside it or not.